# Wrong keyboard position

Tags: code-golf, string, interpreter

You are in fact writing an interpreter for the language "Wrong keyboard position". You can pretend that you are not doing this and just follow the instructions below.

---

I typr re;atively accuratrly, but so,etimes I made a whole nlock of text illegible by shifting a key right. So I need a program that corrects my text back to its original meaning.

### Rules

- You have to *left* shift on a standard English QWERTY keyboard.
- Whitespace do not count for the procedure before left-shifting and are kept as-is in a standard left-shifting procedure. If the key is the leftmost letter/symbol on a keyboard(i.e. `The ~key, Q key, A key, Z key.`), the key is kept as-is. If you reach a control character while left-shifting (`Caps lock and Shift`), their effects will not be triggered and the character before left-shifting is kept.
- This is a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) contest; the shortest answer wins.
- Both the input and the output shall be given via our [default methods](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods).

### Representation of a subset of the QWERTY keyboard that you will need

The two lines connected are possible values of the key: shifted/unshifted.

```
~!@#$%^&*()_+
`1234567890-=

QWERTYUIOP{}|
qwertyuiop[]\

ASDFGHJKL:"
asdfghjkl;'

ZXCVBNM<>?
zxcvbnm,./

(Space)
(Space)
```

### Input

The input will always be a non-empty string conforming the rules above.

### Output

The output will be the input string corrected to the originally intended meaning.

### Examples:

```
Yjod ,sfr yjr, imjsppu/ -> This made them unhaooy.
vpfr hp;g -> code golf
```

Comment: Test case fixed.

Comment: I ported my solution with [almost no change](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/191583/6484), so I'm gonna agree with the duplicate vote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 59 bytes

*-1 byte thanks to Kevin Cruijssen*

```
žVDu«1ú`žhÀ“~!@#$%^&*()_+ `ÿ-=ÿ<>?ÿ:"ÿ{}|ÿ,./ÿ;'ÿ[]\“#vy¦y‡
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AW8AkP9vc2FiaWX//8W@VkR1wqsxw7pgxb5ow4DigJx@IUAjJCVeJiooKV8rIGDDvy09w788Pj/Dvzoiw797fXzDvywuL8O/OyfDv1tdXOKAnCN2ecKmeeKAof//WWpvZCAsc2ZyIHlqciwgaW1qc3BwdS8)

Comment: -1 using `žhÀ` instead of `9LJ`, so the `0` inside the string can be removed (same applies to your [other answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/191583/52210))

Comment: @KevinCruijssen updated both, thanks!